# Deriving location information from a Python boto3 object

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Assuming that I had some boto3 python code that looked like this:

```
import boto3
bucket_name='my_boto_bucket'
boto_rsrc = boto3.resource(
        's3',
        endpoint_url='https://foo.myboto.endpoint.com'
        )
my_bucket = boto_rsrc.Bucket(bucket_name)
```

How can I derive location information from just the my_bucket object?

I crawled the web for hours trying to find a solution and the best answer I could come up would require using the boto_rsrc object itself and calling: `boto_rsrc.meta.client.get_bucket_location(Bucket='bucket_name')`

However, for certain reasons I want to be able to derive this from just the my_bucket object if I can.
Is that technically possible with the current design of boto3?

Comment: **Side-question:** Why are you specifying an endpoint URL? Are you using Amazon S3, or another service?

Comment: The endpoint is actually referring to an S3 compliant installation i.e. CEPH

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you -- there is no `resource` method for getting the location.

Your method of using `meta.client` is a good workaround.

The reality is that the `client` calls all map to actual API calls, while the `resource` calls are simply there to be "more Pythonic". They do not cover all possible API calls. There is no disadvantage to using the client calls to obtain more information.